# Items are not sorted in a tree view in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

There is a very simple tree model example in [Qt document](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/itemviews-simpletreemodel.html). I added a line

```
view.setSortingEnabled(true);
```

in `main.cpp` to enable the tree view sorting. When I run it, I see a sorting indicator in the header. However, no matter how I click the header, the items are not sorted. Is there anything I ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html)  with your view.
The view's `sortingEnabled` property enables the sort buttons in the view. However the actual sorting needs to be implemented in the model's [sort()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#sort) method.
Use QSortFilterProxyModel like this:

```
QSortFilterProxyModel* pProxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(pView);
pProxyModel->setSourceModel(pModel);
pView->setModel(pMdl);
pView->setSortingEnabled(true);
```

Comment: In case I only need to sort items under a parent (not all), any way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: you can take a look at the sort() method or the QSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan() method